# Robot Framework using FlaUILibraray XPath could not be found

Tags: automation, robotframework, flaui

Robot Developer, now entering the world of Windows Application Automation, writing a simple demo using FlaUI Library

```
Test Case FLA
    FlaUILibrary.Launch Application    notepad.exe
    FlaUILibrary.Attach Application By Name    Notepad
    FlaUILibrary.Set Text To Textbox    Name="Text Editor"    Robot Automation POC
    FlaUILibrary.Click    Name=Edit
```

Test fails on "Set Text To Textbox": FlaUiError: Element from XPath 'Name="Text Editor"' could not be found

Same error when I am using XPath "AutomationId=15"

I'm using Automation Spy for inspecting the GUI elements.
Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

XPath specification is more complicated in FlaUI ...

```
FlaUILibrary.Set Text To Textbox    /Window[@Name='Untitled - Notepad']/Document[@Name='Text Editor']    Robot Automation POC
FlaUILibrary.Click    /Window[@Name='Untitled - Notepad']/MenuBar/MenuItem[@Name='Edit']
```

Comment: FlaUI has an inspect tool that could help to find the correct XPATH: https://github.com/FlaUI/FlaUInspect.

Answer (score 0):

As Mr. Roemer himself quotes (see also link below his explanation):

> The XPath FlaUInspect returns is not really correct (and far from efficient), it is only a starting point.
> I should document this better.
> to put more braces around it.
> In your example, probably:
> Instead of:
> /Window/Pane/Pane[1]/Table/Pane[1]/Pane/Pane[1]
> you should use:
> (((/Window/Pane)/Pane[1]/Table)/Pane[1]/Pane)/Pane[1] or something like that. > The XPath syntax is not that easy to use.
> [https://github.com/FlaUI/FlaUI/issues/195#issuecomment-443718720]

I came up with this quick solution yesterday which is not bullet proof at all but at least gives you a start to use paths like:

*/Custom/Custom/Custom/Text* or */Custom/Custom/Text[0]*, etc.

```
    public static AutomationElement GetElementByXPath(string xPath)
    {
        AutomationElement automationElement = ExtendedFramework.window.FindFirstByXPath("/"); //Find top Element
        //string xpath1 = FlaUI.Core.Debug.GetXPathToElement(ExtendedFramework.window);

        string elementPattern = "/";

        string[] getElements = Regex.Split(xPath, elementPattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
        foreach(string element in getElements)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(element)) continue;
            string elementSplitPattern = @"(\[\d\])";
            string[] elements = Regex.Split(element, elementSplitPattern);
            AutomationElement[] automationElements = automationElement.FindAllChildren().Where(x=>x.ControlType.ToString() == elements[0]).ToArray();
            if (elements.Length > 1)
            {
                int index = int.Parse(elements[1].Trim(']').Trim('['));
                automationElement = automationElements[index];
            }
            else
            {
                automationElement = automationElements[0];
            }
        }

        return automationElement;
    }
```

I put this into an extension into my framework and so far, this works like a charm. And even adding something like additional properties in brackets should be no big deal.

as in a comment here before was noticed: TypeOfElementName[@Name='Untitled - Notepad']

etc.

P.S: If anything is still wrong (there's no real error check in there right now) feel free to point it out. I will update here when it makes sense.
And it could be easily turned into an XPath processor "framework" respectively class for FlaUI until a framework integrated solution has arrived.